# Java MySQL JPA aggregate query for contains

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a data set like

```
    COLUMN 1, COLUMN 2, COLUMN 3
    AAA, "red", BB
    AAA, "blue", CC
    BBB, "red", DD
    BBB, "", AA
    CCC, "blue", BB
```

I need a query which shows the distinct list of elements from column 1 has in column 2 the word "red" or not

```
   AAA, "red"
   BBB, "red"
   CCC, ""
```

The indicator can be a boolean or an int or "red" / "" - here I am flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM yourTableName
WHERE column2 = "red"
GROUP BY column1
```

Something like this query would work i guess